# how to select in if statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to test two TaskChangeLogIDs where ID '28' has a NewRollback of 0, and ID '31' has a NewRollback of 1.

I want make sure that depending which ID is called, it selects the correct NewRollback number. I get an error applying the code below in a new window so just need help tweaking this and learn on how to test things like this in the future. I'm getting an error in the IF statement line only.

```
SELECT isnull(NewRollback, 0) FROM Core.TaskChangeLog
WHERE TaskChangeLogID =  28

SELECT isnull(NewRollback, 0) FROM Core.TaskChangeLog
WHERE TaskChangeLogID =  31

IF (NewRollback = 1)

Select * from Core.TaskChangeLog where NewRollback = 1

ELSE
    BEGIN

    Select * from Core.TaskChangeLog where NewRollback = 0

    END
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what error were you getting with the code posted?

Comment: You do know that usually you declare an SQL variable right? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953(v=sql.105).aspx has more information on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `IF` condition to do this just `AND/OR` logic will do the job

Try this way

```
Select * from Core.TaskChangeLog 
where (NewRollback = 1 and askChangeLogID =  28)
   OR (NewRollback = 0 and askChangeLogID =  31)
```

To do some action based on `select` result try this

```
IF EXISTS (Select * from Core.TaskChangeLog 
    where NewRollback = 1 and askChangeLogID =  28) -- Replace with your ID
BEGIN 
 --some action
END
IF EXISTS (Select * from Core.TaskChangeLog 
    where NewRollback = 0 and askChangeLogID =  28)
BEGIN
 --some action
END
```

Answer (score 2):

How about putting all this in one query?  This is my best guess as to the logic you want:

```
Select *
from Core.TaskChangeLog
where NewRollback = (SELECT COALESCE(NewRollback, 0)
                     FROM Core.TaskChangeLog
                     WHERE TaskChangeLogID = XX
                    );
```

Your code fails because the `NewRollback` in the `IF` is undefined.  You could use a variable, but that would just complicate the code.  And, the code should be simplified rather than made more complicated.

Comment: Am I ok to ask Gordon, if I want to execute a particular proc depending on the NewRollback value, then how can I add those? Eg. exec proc1 if New rollback is 1 and exec proc 0 is newrollback is 0

Comment: @BruceyBandit . .  Your question suggests that `NewRollback` is a column in `TaskChangeLog`.  Perhaps you should edit your question (or ask another question) with sample data and explain what you are trying to do.  Perhaps your code isn't clear.